# What are some good options for shell access to a cloud unix account?

Tags: unix, ssh, cloud-storage

I'm interested in keeping a couple of gigabytes of personal files in the cloud with shell access to them. Basically, I want to be able to do something like ssh to a machine that I do not maintain, and do some light programming and file maintenance, and possibly some uploading and downloading.

The reason for this is that I'm hoping to use a Chromebook as my only personal machine, and just ssh to some machine in the cloud for anything I can't do in a browser. I don't need to do any heavy duty programming, but do need to occasionally write some scripts or run latex, so a plain storage solution (e.g., Dropbox, Sugarsync) won't work.

I've tried searching online, but I don't even know what the name of such a service would be, or whether this is even offered commercially. Any advice would be appreciated. Also, if this is the wrong site for this, just let me know where I should ask this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to look for an inexpensive VPS, or Virtual Private Server. This is like a dedicated server offered by a web hosting company, but it's virtualized so generally much less expensive. You can find 'unmanaged' (i.e. without technical support) options for very little. [LowEndBox](http://www.lowendbox.com/) is a website dedicated to discussing such services.